# stri_rand_shuffle internal error depending on how many elements passed at once

Tags: r, stringi

What is the reason for this behavior?

```
x = c(uryat = "uryatg", helyabinsk = "helyabinskj", hukot = "hukoto", 
      huvash = "huvashx", almyk = "almykf", aluga = "alugax", arelia = "areliay", 
      emerovo = "emerovor", hakass = "hakassq", hantymansiy = "hantymansiyb", 
      irov = "irovf", omi = "omie", rasnodar = "rasnodarr", rasnoyarsk = "rasnoyarskj", 
      urgan = "urganu", ursk = "urskm", ordovia = "ordovias", oskva = "oskvaz", 
      urmansk = "urmanskj", ovosibirsk = "ovosibirsku", renburg = "renburgy", 
      rimorye = "rimoryef", akhalin = "akhalinq", molensk = "molenskd", 
      omsk = "omskg", ver = "verk", olgograd = "olgograda", ologda = "ologdaj"
)
set.seed(1)
stringi::stri_rand_shuffle(x)
## Error in stringi::stri_rand_shuffle(x) : internal error
stringi::stri_rand_shuffle(x[1:14])
## Error in stringi::stri_rand_shuffle(x) : internal error
stringi::stri_rand_shuffle(x[1:13])
##  [1] "ygatur"       "bhsenlajkiy"  "ohtkou"       "ahxsvuh"      "kafmly"       "xaluga"       "yarelia"      "remerovo"    
[9] "ohakasq"      "byanitmyhsna" "tshyf"        "nime"         "aorrnador"   
stringi::stri_rand_shuffle(x[14])
## [1] "sarrnyskaoj"
```

seems like nothing about the 14th element should cause the error, yet it does. How do I fix this?

edit
version: stringi_1.2.4 
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)

Comment: can you show the version as i can't reproduce it `stringi::stri_rand_shuffle(x[14])#
[1] "yakajnorrss"`

Comment: if you pass just the 14th one it seems to work, its when its x[1:14] that it fails for me

Comment: that is also working `stringi::stri_rand_shuffle(x[1:14])
 [1] "uygart"       "keslnayjihb"  "khootu"       "ashxuvh"      "kfmlay"       "axagul"      
 [7] "ielraay"      "removero"     "qhasask"      "mahiystynnab" "ifrov"        "emio"        
[13] "oarsrarnd"    "naryasjrsok"`

Comment: maybe it is package version.  I used `packageVersion('stringi')#
[1] ‘1.4.3’`

Comment: Also could not reproduce with 1.4.3.

Comment: updated to 1.4.3 and cant replicate this again